# onTimedText not called for Android 4.1.1

Tags: android, caption

I am trying to add a timedTextTrack to the MediaPlayer using mediaPlayer.addTimedTextSource and mediaPlayer.selectTrack. I am setting a onTimedTextListener to the MediaPlayer as well.

On all other devices with Android version higher than 4.1.1 it is working and I can display the text, but when I try it on the Samsung Tablet GT-P5113 (Android 4.1.1) I get the onTimedText event only once with a null text. While the official documentation is saying that TimedText is supported with these devices.

Does any one know about this issue?

Thank you,

Comment: Can you please mentions the rest of the devices that you have tested on and their Android versions?

Comment: Yes sure! 
Nexus 7 : Android 4.4.2
Galaxy S3 : Android 4.3
Galaxy S3 mini : Android 4.1.2

Comment: Change the name of the srt file to the same name as the video file and give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply but unfortunately it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: I have only one first onTimedText event and the content is null

Comment: I have tried the same on Samsung Tab 2 GT-P3100 running 4.1.2 and it too did not play sub titles

Comment: But according to the docs http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#Multimedia , it should support all devices running 4.1. No idea, why it is not working.